# Is Fog thread-safe?

Tags: ruby, fog

As the title stated, I am writing a script to backup data from **Rackspace** to **S3**. So a more detailed question is whether `fog-aws` and `fog-rackspace` thread-safe or not.

PS: A more generic question, how can I test the thread safety of a block of code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be fine. I'm not sure that it has been extensively tested at this point, but the biggest potential problem is around how the connections/requests are made. These all occur with excon, which is thread-safe to the best of my knowledge, which would lead me to believe that by extension fog should work fine in this regard as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I didn't expect you of all people answering this though. Great work on fog :D

Comment: My pleasure. Definitely let me know if you find anything that points to the contrary. I think it should theoretically be fine, but I don't have a depth of personal experience running this in a multi-threaded fashion.